# Nhibernate won't delete rows while table has trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, triggers

I have the following SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logins](
    [LoginID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AbonnementID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Zeitpunkt] [datetime] NULL,
    [IPAdresse] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IstLogout] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Logins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[LoginID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS      =     ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Logins]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Logins_Abonnements] FOREIGN([AbonnementID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Abonnements] ([AbonnementID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Logins] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Logins_Abonnements]
GO
```

Therefore I created a trigger to write into a ChangeLog:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[LoginsChangeLog]
ON [dbo].[Logins]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LoginID INT
    DECLARE @TypID INT

    SET @TypID = (SELECT ChangeLogTables.ChangeLogTableID FROM ChangeLogTables WHERE ChangeLogTable = 'Logins')
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @LoginID = (SELECT inserted.LoginID FROM inserted)
        INSERT INTO ChangeLog(ChangeLogTableID,ChangeLogTypeID,PrimaryKey) VALUES(@TypID,1, @LoginID)
    END

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @LoginID = (SELECT inserted.LoginID FROM inserted)
        INSERT INTO ChangeLog(ChangeLogTableID,ChangeLogTypeID,PrimaryKey) VALUES(@TypID,2, @LoginID)
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @LoginID = (SELECT deleted.LoginID FROM deleted)
        INSERT INTO ChangeLog(ChangeLogTableID,ChangeLogTypeID,PrimaryKey) VALUES(@TypID,3, @LoginID)
    END
END
```

Adding rows to the table is no problem, trigger completes successfully, but when I try to delete a table with Nhibernate-Framework I get an exception:

> could not execute update query[SQL: delete from Logins where AbonnementID=? and Zeitpunkt

Here is my C# Code:

```
    public void Cleanup(long Id, DateTime time)
    {
        var hqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        hqlBuilder.Append("DELETE Login AS login");
        hqlBuilder.Append(" WHERE login.Abonnement.AbonnementId = :Id");
        hqlBuilder.Append(" AND login.Zeitpunkt < :time ");


        CurrentSession.CreateQuery(hqlBuilder.ToString())
            .SetParameter("Id", Id)
            .SetParameter("time", time)
            .ExecuteUpdate();

    }
```

If I delete my trigger everything works fine, but the trigger has to do his work and write into my Changelog table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trigger is broken because it assumes that `inserted` and `deleted` only contain one row. They may, in fact, contain, 0, 1, or multiple rows. You need to write a trigger that deals with all of those possibilities. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO ChangeLog(ChangeLogTableID,ChangeLogTypeID,PrimaryKey)
SELECT clt.ChangeLogTableID,
   CASE WHEN i.LoginID is not null and d.LoginID is not null THEN 2
        WHEN i.LoginID is not null THEN 1
        ELSE 3 END,
   COALESCE(i.LoginID,d.LoginID)
FROM
   ChangeLogTables clt
      cross join
   (inserted i
      full outer join
   deleted d
      on
         i.LoginID = d.LoginID)
WHERE
   clt.ChangeLogTable = 'Logins'
```

Should replace your entire trigger body.

Comment: Very Nice, thanks alot, but it works fine for inserting and updating, but if i delete the rows, it ´doesn´t fill the ChangeLogTable with TypeID 3 and the TableID.

Comment: @gangfish - minor mistake - I needed to bracket the `()` outer join so that the `cross join` goes to it as a whole. I've added the brackets now (lines 9 and 13)